# how to combine generic `detailsView` and `CreateView` in a single view in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to combine detail and create  in a single view in Django generic views, here is my code :

**models.py**

```py
class Supplier(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=850)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('supplier_details', args=[str(self.id)])


class SupplierItem(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10, default=00.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name
```

**urls.py**

```py
    path('<int:pk>/details', views.SupplierItemsView.as_view(), name="supplier_details"),
```

**views.py**

```py
class SupplierItemsView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SupplierDetailsView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = SupplierItemCreate.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


class SupplierDetailsView(DetailView):
    model = Supplier


class SupplierItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = SupplierItem
    fields = ['item', 'unit_price']
```

Now I want the detail view to be viewed including the create view inside of it, I've tried to render the HTML like this :

**templates/appName/supplieritem_forms.html**

```
<form method="post">

    {{ form }}

</form>
```

**templates/appName/supplier_detail.html**

```
....
{% include 'profiture_supplier/supplieritem_form.html' %}
....
```

The result that it shows the details HTML view rendered perfect, but the form is never shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a form and used it by mixing both views like this :

```py
class SupplierDetailsView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Supplier
    form_class = SupplierItemForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SupplierDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return FormView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```